# $\sin{\frac{\arccos(1-2x)}{2}}$ simplification without prior knowledge of the solution

Tags: trigonometry

I managed to, in the wild, acquire the function $f(x) = \sin{\frac{\arccos(1-2x)}{2}}$. I checked using Wolfram Alpha for possible simplifications, and found out that it equals (hover to show):

> $\sqrt{x}$

I struggled to understand the reasons for this, and discovered this question asking about an equivalent problem (title provides the answer in a different form):

> [How to prove $2\arccos(x)+\arccos(1-2x^2)=π$ on $x\in[0,1]$ from MVT](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415599/how-to-prove-2-arccosx-arccos1-2x2-%cf%80-on-x-in0-1-from-mvt)

But this form of the question seems much more like an exercise than a problem-solving step-by-step method. How can one discover this relationship without prior knowledge of it (either from empirical graphed data or from an exercise)?

Comment: Use round brackets rather than curly ones around a mathematical function's argument, as in my edit. Curly brackets, or braces, are for arguments of MathJaX functions such as `\operatorname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\theta:=\arccos(1-2x)$ so $x=\frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}=\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}$ and $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=\pm\sqrt{x}$. But an arccosine $\in[0,\,\pi]$, so $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\ge0$ and $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=\sqrt{x}$.